# Extending the domains of densely defined bounded integral transforms on $L^2(\Bbb R)$

Tags: functional-analysis, integral-transforms

This is a question I've contemplated for quite some time since it's pretty closely related to Fourier theory (particularly choosing the "right" space to define the Fourier transform on). However I've never been able to come up with anything resembling an answer for this. Nor have I seen it be addressed anywhere.

Let $X$ be dense in $L^2(\Bbb R)$ and $T:X\subseteq L^2(\Bbb R)\to L^2(\Bbb R)$ be the integral operator given by

$$ Tf(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} k(y,x) f(x)\,dx$$

where the integral is the Lebesgue integral. Assume that $T$ is bounded. If $g\in L^2(\Bbb R)\setminus X$ but we have that

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |k(y,x)| |g(x)|\,dx < \infty$$

for each $y$ (i.e. $Tg$ is well-posed). Is it necessarily the case that $Tg$ is in $L^2(\Bbb R)$? Note here that $T$ is meant as an integral transform, not the extension of $T$ (since that would be true trivially). My first approach was to consider some limit of elements in $X$ which approach $g$ in $L^2$, but I couldn't really piece any more of an argument together since it wasn't obvious to me how to proceed.

---

A partial attempt:

Since $X$ is dense in $L^2(\Bbb R)$, there is a a sequence $(f_m)\subseteq X$ such that $f_m\to g$ in $L^2(\Bbb R)$. Since $L^p$ convergence implies pointwise almost everywhere convergence of a subsequence $(f_{m_k})$ to $g$. Moreover, $f_{m_k}\to g$ in $L^2(\Bbb R)$.

Since $f_{m_k}(x) \to g(x)$ for almost every $x$, we have that $k(y,x) f_{m_k}(x) \to k(y,x)g(x)$ almost everywhere. **Assuming** that it can be shown that

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} k(y,x) f_{m_k}(x)\,dx\to \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} k(y,x)g(x)\,dx,\tag{1}$$

then since $(f_{m_k})$ is Cauchy and $T$ is bounded, $(Tf_{m_k})$ is Cauchy and thus converges to an element of $L^2(\Bbb R)$. This then says that

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} k(y,x) g(x)\,dx = \lim_k \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} k(y,x) f_{m_k}(x)\,dx = \lim_k Tf_{m_k}(y).$$

Since $\lim_k Tf_{m_k}\in L^2(\Bbb R)$, we'd have that $Tg\in L^2(\Bbb R)$ since they agree almost everywhere.

This is predicated on $(1)$ being true. $(1)$ can be shown if dominated convergence can be applied, though it isn't clear that the $k(y,\cdot)f_{m_k}$ can be bounded uniformly by an integrable function for a fixed but arbitrary $y$. If $g$ could be approximated within by elements in $X$, then this would work, but that is a very strong condition and will not be the case in general.

Comment: If $X$ is nice enough, this will certainly hold. For example, if $X$ contains all step functions (simple functions), then you can find a sequence $(f_n)_n$ in $X$ with $|f_n| \leq 2|f|$ and $f_n \to f$ pointwise. It is then not hard to see $f_n \to f$ in $L^2$, so that we get $T f_n \to Tf$, but using dominated convergence, we also get $\int k(y,x) f_n \, dx \to \int k(y,x) f(x) \, dx$, so that the integral-operator-function coincides with $Tf$ (almost everywhere). In general however, things will probably get hairy :)

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. The general case does seem pretty rough though. Using the fact that $L^2$ convergence implies pointwise (a.e.) convergence of a subsequence might be useful but it's not obvious to me where to go from there.

Comment: There are several good reasons for defining the Fourier transform on $L^{1}\cap L^{2}$, which includes compactly supported $L^{2}$ functions. More general Fourier transforms are defined on compactly supported $L^{2}$ functions.

Comment: @CameronWilliams : Are you assuming that, for $f \in X$, you have $\int |k(y,x)||f(y)|dy < \infty$ for a.e. $x$? Or are you defining the "integral operator" in some other sense?

Comment: @TrialAndError Oh yes I should say that for $f\in X$, the integral does exist in the Lebesgue sense, but it has the added property that $Tf$ is in $L^2(\Bbb R)$.

Comment: Strikes me as a Good Question, because it's the sort of thing that people often just sort of gloss over when they're talking about specific operators. Not that I know the answer - if I knew the answer it would be an Excellent Question. heh...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Haha. Yeah it's a bit odd to me that it's a question that's swept under the rug but it underlies a lot of Fourier transform theory (and more generally integral operator theory). Maybe it's that there isn't a good answer known.

Comment: Of course I wasn't really casting doubt on any of those places where it does get sort of ignored - typically in the case of an explicit operator it's not hard to show it's true. But it's a good question. My conjecture is it's false in general. No evidence except I just don't see any reason it should be true in general...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a silly counterexample which nevertheless shows what is possible.

Let $k(y,x)=1$ for all $x,y$ and define
$$
X=\left\{ f \in L^1 \cap L^2 \, \middle| \,\int f(x)\, dx=0\right\}.
$$

Note that $X$ is a subspace of $L^2$ which is dense, since for $f\in C_c$, we can set $\alpha =\int f \, dx$ and $f_n = f -\alpha/n\cdot 1_{[0,n]}$. It is easy to see that the "added" term goes to zero in $L^2$ and hence $f_n \to f$ with $f_n \in X$.

Also, on $X$, the integral operator satisfies $T \equiv 0$, which is certainly bounded :)

Finally, for every function $f\in L^2$ with
$$
\int |k(y,x) f(x)|\, dx <\infty,
$$
we have $f\in L^1$ and applying the  integral operator yields the **constant** function $T f \equiv \alpha$ with $\alpha =\int f \, dx$. Hence, $Tf\in L^2$ iff $\alpha =0$ iff $f \in X$.

Comment: Hmm that certainly is interesting and definitely a little "silly", but I think it gets the idea across pretty well. Integral transforms are very finicky beasts. Even making sure that most of the desired properties are there doesn't grant you what you want. I sometimes wonder why I study integral transforms at all haha.